# Can I use the handle of an external process using DuplicateHandle?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I understand from the signature and [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx) of `DuplicateHandle` that I can duplicate a handle from an external (possibly unrelated) process, given that I have permission and know both the process ID and the handle value. Is that true?

If so, which permissions must be granted to the processes and/or handles?

Comment: You might also need some synchronisation.  You need the PID, but also you need to make sure the process has actually opened the handle (`WaitForInputIdle` is sometimes useful).  The owning process also must not close the handle (or shut down) until you have duplicated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the documentation for [DuplicateHandle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx):

> hSourceProcessHandle [in]
>
> A handle to the process with the handle to be duplicated.
>
> The handle must have the PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE access right.

So the ACL for the remote process must grant you `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` and you must request that right when calling [OpenProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx).

Handles themselves do not have ACLs.  Provided you have `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` you can duplicate any valid handle in the process.

Comment: Yes, I had seen it but the code I wrote was always returning `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. It turned out that the error was in another part of the code that searched the handle value. Thanks for the confirmation, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have duplicate handle from any process, if you can open it with PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE access right. if you know process ID - possible you can open the process. about handle permission, usually DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS flag used and you got same permission in new handle